# How to properly use cURL --data-binary to send a request payload

Tags: http, file-upload, curl, http2

This question is out of pure curiosity. I know I can send multipart formposts using curl's `--form`/`-F` option. However, I was curious to see if the same can be done with the `--data-binary` option? For example, if I run the following script to send a request to a PortSwigger Lab titled **Web shell upload via Content-Type restriction bypass**:

```
#!/usr/bin/env zsh

printf "\nsending request method: POST ..\n"
curl -X POST \
"https://0a0b0059048a431b81ed7643003d0052.web-security-academy.net/my-account/avatar" \
-H 'Host: 0a0b0059048a431b81ed7643003d0052.web-security-academy.net' \
-H 'User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:121.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/121.0' \
-H 'Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8' \
-H 'Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.5' \
-H 'Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br' \
-H 'Content-Type: multipart/form-data' \
-H 'Content-Length: 38849' \
-H 'Origin: https://0a0b0059048a431b81ed7643003d0052.web-security-academy.net' \
-H 'Connection: keep-alive' \
-H 'Referer: https://0a0b0059048a431b81ed7643003d0052.web-security-academy.net/my-account' \
-H 'Cookie: session=whnYtIxrymdpB2B0GfAmcHSL0JZ7PHYd' \
-H 'Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1' \
-H 'Sec-Fetch-Dest: document' \
-H 'Sec-Fetch-Mode: navigate' \
-H 'Sec-Fetch-Site: same-origin' \
-H 'Sec-Fetch-User: ?1' \
--data-binary '@./reqsPayload.txt' \
--compressed -i > resp.txt
```

I get this response:

```
sending request method: POST ..                                                                                                                     
Warning: Couldn't read data from file "reqsPayload.txt", this makes an empty                                                                        
Warning: POST.                                                                                                                                      
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current                                                                     
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed                                                                       
100    46  100    46    0     0     18      0  0:00:02  0:00:02 --:--:--    18                                                                      
                                                                                                                                                    
displaying response: filtered ..                                                                                                                    
HTTP/2 400                                                                                                                                          
content-type: application/json; charset=utf-8                                                                                                       
x-frame-options: SAMEORIGIN                                                                                                                         
content-encoding: gzip                                                                                                                              
content-length: 46                                                                                                                                  
                                                                                                                                                    
"Missing parameter 'csrf'"
```

Note: the file `reqsPayload.txt` contains the following request payload:

```
-----------------------------56824688216260865592753826511
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="avatar"; filename="file.jpg"
Content-Type: image/jpeg

./path/to/file.jpg
-----------------------------56824688216260865592753826511
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="user"

wiener
-----------------------------56824688216260865592753826511
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="csrf"

tOIh5UdsjYqWPRyc7ZKpwYysD3EDdfUF
-----------------------------56824688216260865592753826511--
```

What am I missing? I can clearly see the csrf token, even though the response includes *"Missing parameter 'csrf'"*. And how do I fix the other response *Warning: Couldn't read data from file "reqsPayload.txt"*?

Cheers.

Comment: `reqsPayload.txt` is actually a JSON or what? I don't think you can reference a non-JSON like that, but you can prove me wrong.

Comment: that'll be sent as binary data...  For the couldn't read data warning, I would check path... might need an absolute path to the file or try with @reqsPayload.txt